# Isolating my signal to just me

Tags: live-sound

I’m a guitarist and when on stage, I want to be able to switch between my signal going to the main pa / front of house as usual, and to a personal monitor so only I can hear myself play (eg if it’s a new song, I can quickly work out the key etc before letting anyone hear me!).

Has anyone done this before? Any advice on gear required and appropriate setup is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Doing this all the time! Just play quietly until you know what you're doing! Or use in ear monitors. If you can't get there within a few bars, maybe re-consider.

Comment: I also do that Tim, thanks.Re in ear monitors, I was wanting a solution where I could hear what goes out ‘live’ but I was wanting just a switch where I could just have the signal go to me in this situation.

Comment: You're in a performance situation where you're being put through the PA - therefore presumably there's a sizeable audience - and the band's feeling its way through unknown material?   Seems a bit unlikely!

Answer (score 1):

If they are miking your cab, an in-ear (or roland cube put on a boom stand) with an ABY box solution would work.

An example of this setup would be such... All your fx into an ABY switch into the Y jack. A would go to your guitar amp, and B would go to in ear/monitor.

This way, you could use in-ear all the time, but pull yourself out of the house by turning A off. You might need some sort of preamp/poweramp setup to get the desired output from your guitar to your monitoring/in-ear depending on the monitoring system you use.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for an ABY pedal. Several models exist but the purpose of those pedals is just to allow you to switch between two different outputs (or switch between two different inputs but it won't be useful if your case).

If you keep the main sound system on one output and a personal sound system on the other one, you will be able to switch easily between the two.